# CloudKit Query works on Xcode release build, not on TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Here's my problem: my app fetches records from CloudKit fine when connected to Xcode on my phone (using a Release scheme), but when I release it on TestFlight, it won't fetch the records.

Here's my fetching function:

```
func allprevFacts(date: String, olddate: Int){
        act.startAnimating()
        let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
        //let factPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID = %@", CKRecordID(recordName: date))
        let factPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "date <= %@", NSDate())
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "BirdFacts", predicate: factPredicate)
        publicDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }
            else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    //print(results)
                    var count = 0
                    var sortedresults = [Int]()
                    for result in results! {
                        var b = result.valueForKey("sortingDate") as! Int
                        sortedresults.append(b)
                    }
                    print(sortedresults)
                    while count < sortedresults.count {
                        if sortedresults[count] <= olddate {
                            sortedresults.removeAtIndex(count)
                        }
                        else {
                            count = count + 1
                        }
                    }
                    print(sortedresults)
                    while sortedresults.count > 0 {
                        var d: Int = 0
                        let a = sortedresults[sortedresults.endIndex-1]
                        print(a)
                        while d < sortedresults.count{
                            if sortedresults[d] == a {
                                sortedresults.removeAtIndex(d)
                                self.birdFacts.append(results![d])
                                self.tableFacts.reloadData()
                                self.tableFacts.hidden = false
                            }
                            d = d + 1
                            print(d)
                        }
                    }
                    self.saveFacts()
                    print("saving bird facts")
                    self.tableFacts.hidden = false
                }
            }
        }
        act.stopAnimating()
    }
```

Here's the iPhone console output when I launch the app (and it should run the CloudKit query):

> Jun  8 09:15:06 Alexs-iPhone SpringBoard[63] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  8
>   09:15:06 Alexs-iPhone SpringBoard[63] :  SecTrustEvaluate 
>   [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Jun  8 09:15:06 Alexs-iPhone
>   kernel[0] : xpcproxy[468] Container:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/85885117-5626-4CC1-90B4-A7C14F5C9AE5
>   (sandbox) Jun  8 09:15:06 Alexs-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
>   : assertion failed: 13F69: launchd + 116796
>   [9F6284CF-8A17-36CC-9DB5-85D510A21F14]: 0x3 Jun  8 09:15:07
>   Alexs-iPhone limitadtrackingd[463] : Lost connection from
>   Limit Ad Tracking client. Jun  8 09:15:07 Alexs-iPhone
>   limitadtrackingd[463] : Lost connection from Limit Ad
>   Tracking client. Jun  8 09:15:08 Alexs-iPhone SpringBoard[63]
>   : Application
>   'UIKitApplication:com.apple.AdSheetPhone[0x5386]' exited voluntarily.
>   Jun  8 09:15:08 Alexs-iPhone UserEventAgent[26] :
>   94505698100: id=com.apple.AdSheetPhone pid=464, state=0 Jun  8
>   09:15:08 Alexs-iPhone cloudd[197] :  no delegate for <__NSCFLocalDataTask: 0x103d617c0>{
>   taskIdentifier: 11 } { completed } (CKDQueryURLRequest
>   requestUUID:22D6A501-9D0B-4388-8316-431100DA5BE3) in session
>   <__NSURLSessionLocal: 0x1002ddd80> for call
>   URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: Jun  8 09:15:18 Alexs-iPhone
>   assistantd[30] : tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp
>   13 __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error
>   22 Jun  8 09:15:18 Alexs-iPhone assistantd[30] :
>   NSURLSessionStreamTask: TCPConnection read invalidated by closed
>   connection Jun  8 09:15:18 Alexs-iPhone networkd[100] :
>   -[NETAWDManager reportStats:metricID:] AWDServerConnection newMetricContainerWithIdentifier failed for metric 2686980, server
>   0x14562a930, not reporting:    {
>         "client_id" = assistantd;
>         "establishment_cellular_fallback" = 0;
>         "establishment_failure_error" = 0;
>         "establishment_forced_tcp_fallback" = 0;
>         "establishment_interface_name" = en0;
>         "establishment_success" = 1;
>         "establishment_syn_retransmits" = 0;
>         "establishment_tcp_fallback" = 0;
>         "establishment_time" = "0.05480975";
>         "interface_reports" =     (
>                     {
>                 "data_in_KB" = 0;
>                 "data_out_KB" = 0;
>                 "interface_name" = "pdp_ip0";
>                 "post_connect_subflow_failure_errors" =             (
>                 );
>                 "post_connect_tcp_fallback_count" = 0;
>                 "secondary_flow_failure_count" = 0;
>                 "secondary_flow_success_count" = 1;
>             },
>                     {
>                 "data_in_KB" = 5;
>                 "data_out_KB" = 2;
>                 "interface_name" = en0;
>                 "post_connect_subflow_failure_errors" =             (
>                 );
>                 "post_connect_tcp_fallback_count" = 0;
>                 "secondary_flow_failure_count" = 0;
>                 "secondary_flow_success_count" = 0;
>             }
>         );
>         "post_connect_multi_homed" = 1;
>         "post_connect_session_lifetime" = "42.576455291";
>         "post_connect_single_homed" = 0;
>         "post_connect_subflow_attempt_count" = 2;
>         "post_connect_subflow_max_subflow_count" = 2;
>         "subflow_switching_count" = 0;  } Jun  8 09:15:19 Alexs-iPhone SpringBoard[63] : [* error]: XPC Error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named
>   com.apple.coreduetd.knowledge was invalidated from this process."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.coreduetd.knowledge was invalidated from this process.}

I can't make head or tails of the error code, does anyone have some suggestions on what might be going wrong?

Comment: have you moved your container to production from the cloudkit dashboard?

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you!!

Comment: I have put it in an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you distribute an app with TestFlight, that app will use the production container. Before you can use that app, you have to move your container into production. You can do that from the CloudKit dashboard.

Select your container. Click in the menu on 'Deployment'. Then Click on the button 'Deploy to production' and follow the instructions.

Comment: That's what I was afraid I was going to find.  How frustrating.  I was hoping to have the production database clean for launch, post beta.